# Unknown host and not sudo anymore

Tags: sudo, hosts

I have had ubuntu for a while now, but for some reason I am no longer a sudo.

When I open up terminal and type the command

```
sudo false
sudo unknown host HOST
```

then when I actually look at my hosts file I see DIFFERNTHOST

the problem is I cant change my host because I am not a sudo so I am locked out of my computer and I can't do anything!

Note: I have already tried editing my /etc/hosts file and I cant edit it

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Live USB or CD, remount your `/` disk partition `rw` and look at/fix (on the disk filesystem, which I will assume you mount at `/mnt/tmp`) `/mnt/tmp/etc/sudoers` and `/mnt/tmp/etc/sudoers.d/*`